# Partial upgrade to 20.04 LTS - incorrect version of libapt-pkg

Tags: apt, upgrade, 20.04, do-release-upgrade, aptitude

I am trying to upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04:

```
$ grep -i rel /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_RELEASE=20.04
```

It looks like there is a dependency issue:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://no.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://no.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease       
Hit:3 http://no.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease     
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Traceback (most recent call last):                
  File "/usr/lib/cnf-update-db", line 8, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound.db.creator import DbCreator
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/db/creator.py", line 11, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ImportError: libapt-pkg.so.6.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in <module>
    from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 24, in <module>
    import apt
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ImportError: libapt-pkg.so.6.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/cnf-update-db", line 8, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound.db.creator import DbCreator
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/db/creator.py", line 11, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ImportError: libapt-pkg.so.6.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Reading package lists... Done
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/lib/command-not-found/ -a -e /usr/lib/cnf-update-db; then /usr/lib/cnf-update-db > /dev/null; fi'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

I seems I have the old **libapt-pkg.so.5.0** instead of the new and expected **libapt-pkg.so.6.0**:

```
sudo updatedb && locate libapt-pkg.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-pkg.so.5.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-pkg.so.5.0.2
```

Any hints on how to repair?

Update after helpful hints from MAV:

```
$ wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apt/libapt-pkg6.0_2.0.2ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb
$ sudo dpkg -i libapt-pkg6.0_2.0.2ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb 
$ sudo apt-get update
Reading package lists... Done  
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
<..lot of packages..>
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
$ sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0 : Breaks: gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0:i386 (!= 2.36.11-2) but 2.40.0+dfsg-3 is installed
 gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0:i386 : Depends: gir1.2-glib-2.0:i386 (>= 0.9.3) but it is not installed
                             Depends: libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:i386 (>= 2.39.2) but it is not installed
                             Breaks: libgtk3-perl (< 0.034-2~) but 0.032-1 is installed
                             Breaks: gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0 (!= 2.40.0+dfsg-3) but 2.36.11-2 is installed
 gir1.2-gtk-3.0 : Depends: gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0 (>= 2.40.0) but 2.36.11-2 is installed
                  Depends: gir1.2-pango-1.0 (>= 1.41.0) but 1.40.14-1ubuntu0.1 is installed
                  Depends: libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.24.7) but 3.22.30-1ubuntu4 is installed
 gnupg : Depends: gpgv (>= 2.2.19-3ubuntu2)
 hplip : Depends: hplip-data (= 3.20.3+dfsg0-2) but 3.17.10+repack0-5 is installed
         Depends: libhpmud0 (= 3.20.3+dfsg0-2) but 3.17.10+repack0-5 is installed
         Depends: printer-driver-hpcups (= 3.20.3+dfsg0-2) but 3.17.10+repack0-5 is installed
 libsane-hpaio : Depends: libhpmud0 (>= 3.20.3+dfsg0) but 3.17.10+repack0-5 is installed
 python3-brlapi : Depends: libbrlapi0.7 but it is not installed
 python3-dev : Depends: libpython3-dev (= 3.8.2-0ubuntu2) but 3.6.7-1~18.04 is installed
               Depends: python3.8-dev (>= 3.8.2-1~) but it is not installed
 python3-gi : Depends: libgirepository-1.0-1 (>= 1.62.0-4~) but 1.56.1-1 is installed
 python3-pil : Depends: libimagequant0 (>= 2.11.10) but it is not installed
 python3-protobuf : Depends: libprotobuf17 but it is not installed
 python3-uno : Depends: libreoffice-core (= 1:6.4.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) but 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.10 is installed or
                        libreoffice-core-nogui (= 1:6.4.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) but it is not installed
               Depends: libuno-cppu3 (>= 4.4.0~alpha) but it is not installed
               Depends: libuno-cppuhelpergcc3-3 (>= 5.3.0~alpha) but it is not installed
               Depends: libuno-sal3 (>= 5.4.0~alpha) but it is not installed
               Depends: libuno-salhelpergcc3-3 (>= 3.6.0~beta) but it is not installed
               Depends: uno-libs-private but it is not installed
 rhythmbox-plugins : Depends: librhythmbox-core10 (= 3.4.4-1ubuntu2) but 3.4.2-4ubuntu1 is installed
                     Depends: rhythmbox (= 3.4.4-1ubuntu2) but 3.4.2-4ubuntu1 is installed
                     Depends: gir1.2-rb-3.0 (= 3.4.4-1ubuntu2) but 3.4.2-4ubuntu1 is installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
$
```

So I guess I can manually upgrade and/or purge packages now?

Answer (score 4):

I assume your arch is amd64.

Try `cd /tmp;wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apt/libapt-pkg6.0_2.0.2ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb;sudo dpkg -i libapt-pkg6.0_2.0.2ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb` from a terminal and see if that gets you going.

You mentioned the aptitude tag.  Please post the output of `aptitude search ~b` if above command sequence does not get you unstuck.

Comment: Thanks, that certainly got the libapt-pkg installed!

Comment: That's excellent news.

As the next step I would suggest to use `aptitude` now to see if it can find a way forward out of this mess.  `sudo aptitude` and then type g to see how it would try to resolve the situation.  Use the aptitude resolver by marking suggestions as either accepted or rejected.  Maybe there's a Youtube video out there or https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/aptitude/ch02s03s05.en.html can help you.  This will now be a bit of a game of patience.  When you are in the main view of aptitude and hit b, you will jump to the next broken package and inspect what the problem is.

Comment: It is a very worthwhile piece of software to learn.

Comment: Try to make sure perl is updated first as a lot of other stuff depends on it.  You can also hold certain parts of your system to what's currently there and only update others.  When you are in the resolver then you can use `,` and `.` to move between solutions.  `F10 ` gives you the menu.  It's the command-line but still novice-friendly.

Comment: This still works as long as you change `ubuntu0.1` to `ubuntu0.2` in both places. `cd /tmp;wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apt/libapt-pkg6.0_2.0.2ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb;sudo dpkg -i libapt-pkg6.0_2.0.2ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb`

Answer (score 1):

The above command worked for me on Ubuntu 20.04, but I was still getting errors like this:

```
$ sudo apt-get upgrade 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
/usr/lib/ubuntu-advantage/apt-esm-hook: error while loading shared libraries: libapt-pkg.so.5.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
/usr/lib/ubuntu-advantage/apt-esm-hook: error while loading shared libraries: libapt-pkg.so.5.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I managed to overcome it by re installing `ubuntu-advantage-tools`

```
sudo apt-get install -y ubuntu-advantage-tools
```